# bicep azure web app code fails with There was a conflict. Conflict with existing ScmType: ExternalGit

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-bicep

I have written IaC in Bicep to deploy an Azure web application, works fine however when executed for the first time, it works fine however when executed a second time it fails with the error below. It is complaining about a conflict with the ScmType.

From the research that I have done, it appears to be an issue with ARM, however I have not come across a solution for bicep.

https://github.com/Azure/bicep-types-az/issues/1510

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/879179/deploying-web-app-with-there-was-a-conflict-confli

`{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource \"message\": \"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.\",\r\n        \"details\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n            \"message\": \"{\\r\\n  \\\"Code\\\": \\\"BadRequest\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"Message\\\": \\\"There was a conflict. Conflict with existing ScmType: ExternalGit\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"Target\\\": null,\\r\\n  \\\"Details\\\": [\\r\\n    {\\r\\n      \\\"Message\\\": \\\`

Main.bicep

```
//az deployment sub create --name create_rg --template-file .\main.bicep --parameters .\parameters.dev.json --location UKSouth --output jsonc 

// main.bicep

targetScope = 'subscription'

param appServicePlan object

param webApp object

param resGroup object

param SharedresGroup object

param keyvault object

param appServicePlanOS string = 'windows'

param networkConfig object

param database object

var linuxOffer = 'linux'

var windowsOffer = 'windows'

module createMainRG './modules/resourceGroup/create_rg.bicep' = {

  name:'CreateMainResourceGroup'

  params: {

    paramRGName: resGroup.name

  }

}

module appPlan 'modules/appService/appServicePlan.bicep' = {

  scope: rg

  name: appServicePlan.name

  params: {

    appServicePlanNameParam: appServicePlan.name

    appServicePlanSkuParam: appServicePlan.sku

    environmentParam: resGroup.tags.Environment

    os: appServicePlan.os

  }

}

module app 'modules/appService/webApp.bicep' = {

  scope: rg

  name: 'webAppConfig'

  params: {

    appServicePlanIdParam: appPlan.outputs.aspId

    environmentParam: resGroup.tags.Environment

    linuxFxVersionParam: webApp.linuxFxVersion

    webAppNameParam: webApp.name

  }

}

module appConfig 'modules/appService/webAppConfiguration.bicep' = {

  scope: rg

  name: webApp.name

  params: {

    ConfigappServicePlanIdParam: appPlan.outputs.aspId

    ConfigenvironmentParam: resGroup.tags.Environment

    ConfiglinuxFxVersionParam: webApp.linuxFxVersion

    ConfigwebAppNameParam: webApp.name

    kvName: resourceKeyVaultModule.outputs.name

  }

  dependsOn: [

    app

  ]

}
```

``./modules/appService/appServicePlan.bicep`

```
param appServicePlanNameParam string

param appServicePlanSkuParam object

param environmentParam string

param os string

var appServicePlanName = '${appServicePlanNameParam}'

var location = resourceGroup().location

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-12-01' = {

  name: appServicePlanName

  location: location

  kind: 'windows'

  properties: {

    reserved: ((os == 'linux') ? true : false)

  }

  sku: appServicePlanSkuParam

}

output aspId string = appServicePlan.id
```

./modules/webApp.bicep

```
// modules/webApp.bicep

param appServicePlanIdParam string

param environmentParam string

param linuxFxVersionParam string

param webAppNameParam string

var webAppName = '${webAppNameParam}'

var location = resourceGroup().location

 

resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-12-01' = {

  name: webAppName

  location: location

  tags: {}

  properties: {

    metadata: [

      {

        name: 'Current_Stack'

        value: 'dotnet|4.0'

      }

      {

        name: 'alwaysOn'

        value: true

      }

    ]

    serverFarmId: appServicePlanIdParam

    httpsOnly: true

  }

  identity:{

    type: 'SystemAssigned'

  }

}

resource appServiceStack 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2020-12-01' = {

  name: '${webApp.name}/metadata'

  kind: 'web'

  properties:{

    CURRENT_STACK: 'Java'

  }

  dependsOn:[

  ]

}

resource srcControls 'Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols@2020-12-01' = {

  name: '${webApp.name}/web'

  properties:{

    repoUrl: 'https://github.com/vanderby/SonarQube-AzureAppService'

    branch: 'master'

    isManualIntegration: true

  }

}

output sysIdentity string = webApp.identity.principalId
```

modules/appService/webApp.bicep

```
// modules/appService/webApp.bicep

param ConfigappServicePlanIdParam string

param ConfigenvironmentParam string

param ConfiglinuxFxVersionParam string

param ConfigwebAppNameParam string

param kvName string

var webAppName = '${ConfigwebAppNameParam}'

var location = resourceGroup().location

resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-12-01' = {

  name: webAppName

  location: location

  tags: {}

  properties: {

    metadata: [

      {

        name: 'Current_Stack'

        value: 'dotnet|4.0'

      }

      {

        name: 'alwaysOn'

        value: true

      }

    ]

    siteConfig: {

      appSettings: [

        {

          name: 'SonarQubeEdition'

          value: 'developer'

        }

        {

          name: 'SonarQubeVersion'

          value: '9.9.1.69595'

        }

  

      ]

       windowsFxVersion: ConfiglinuxFxVersionParam

      netFrameworkVersion: 'v4.0'

      alwaysOn: true         

      

      

      phpVersion: '5.6'

      requestTracingEnabled: false

      remoteDebuggingEnabled: false

      httpLoggingEnabled: false

      acrUseManagedIdentityCreds: false

      logsDirectorySizeLimit: 35

      detailedErrorLoggingEnabled: false

      publishingUsername: webAppName

     // scmType: 'ExternalG

      use32BitWorkerProcess: true

      webSocketsEnabled: false

      javaVersion: '17'

      javaContainer: 'TOMCAT'

      javaContainerVersion: '9.0'

      managedPipelineMode: 'Integrated'

      

    }

 

    serverFarmId: ConfigappServicePlanIdParam

  }

}

resource srcControls 'Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols@2020-12-01'={

  parent: webApp

  name: 'web'

  properties:{

    repoUrl: 'https://github.com/vanderby/SonarQube-AzureAppService'

    branch: 'master'

    isManualIntegration: false

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is related to the conflict with `SCM type`. Usually, this happens when you try to redeploy the web application with a different `ScmType` property value than the one that is currently set.

*Need to check below to resolve this:*

- When you have modified the configurations in the bicep script and deploying it, make sure that you deleted the existed web application and then deploy to avoid conflicts.
- If you are changing the `scm type` value every time before deploying, then conditionally sets the `ScmType` property based on whether it already exists or not. you may use an `if condition` to determine whether the web application already exists and set the `ScmType` accordingly.

I tried the same code as you and was deployed successfully as shown:

[image]

[image]

*When you redeploy the application, the conflict concerns should go away. If still the issue persists, try raising a support request in Microsoft support.*

Refer [deployment error for bicep templates](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/overview.md) as it is related to deployment specific issues.

Comment: Thanks for this, will the `IF` condition be within the bicep IaC and do you have an example ?

Comment: Refer this for [conditional statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/conditional-resource-deployment) in bicep.